# PowerApps Data Collection Issue

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection

So I'm having an issue specifically returning data from a MS Graph call Flow but only at the response/data collection part of the call.

So I run the flow from PowerApps with a meeting room's id. Once I do that, I make the necessary calls and after manipulating the data, I get a response that looks like the following:

```
[
 {
  "Subject": "Fun Meeting",
  "Start": "1/22/2019 9:00 AM",
  "End": "1/22/2019 12:00 PM"
 },
 {
  "Subject": "Boring Meeting",
  "Start": "1/22/2019 1:00 PM",
  "End": "1/22/2019 4:00 PM"
 }
]
```

However, when I Collect this data back in powerapps, it all ends up on one row as an example below.

```
Events                          Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Fun Meeting; Boring Meeting  | 9:00 AM - 12:00PM; 1:00 PM - 4:00 PM; |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The PowerApps documentation states that the collect data source should look like the response above so I'm not sure why it's all being thrown into the same row?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

Created a PowerApps Flow with response Action
[image: Flow Returns collection]

The 'Response Body JSON Schema' was created with the given Response.

In PowerApps I was able to collect the data with

```
ClearCollect(colEvents,LoadCollection.Run())
```

Whith leads to this Collection in PowerApps

[image: Collection in Powerapps collected from Flow]